# What's the fastest way to get CSV output into a data frame?

Tags: r

I have a program that outputs lines of CSV data that I want to load into a data frame.
I currently load the data like so:

```
tmpFilename <- "tmp_file"
system(paste(procName, ">", tmpFilename), wait=TRUE)
myData <- read.csv(tmpFilename) # (I also pass in colClasses and nrows for efficiency)
```

However, I thought redirecting the output to a file just to read from it was inefficient (the program spits out about 30MB, so I want to handle it with optimal performance). I thought `textConnection` would solve this, so I tried:

```
con <- textConnection(system(procName, intern=TRUE))
myData <- read.csv(con)
```

This runs a lot slower, though, and whereas the first solution degrades linearly with input size, the `textConnection` solution's performance degrades exponentially it seems. The slowest part is creating the `textConnection`. `read.csv` here actually completes quicker than in the first solution since it's reading from memory.

My question is then, is creating a file just to run `read.csv` on it my best option with respect to speed? Is there a way to speed up the creation of a textConnection? bonus: why is creating a textConnection so slow?

Comment: It appears that you're creating an extra vector containing the entire output, with `intern=TRUE`.  That vector will continue to grow as output is produced, which will continually allocate memory.  If you split that line into two commands, `output <- system(procname, intern=TRUE); con <- textConnection(output)`, I highly suspect that the `system` command will be taking most of the time.

Comment: right, so if I split it up, the longest statement is the `textConnection(output)` call. By "longest", I mean `system` takes a couple seconds, `read.csv` takes another couple seconds, `textConnection()` takes 4 minutes.

Comment: Wow.  What OS is this?  If it's Linux, I would create the file under `/dev/shm` which will use nothing but RAM.

Comment: yes, Linux. However, some users will be Windows users. Ideally, I'd get a solution for both, but that's still a handy tip

Comment: Possibly helpful:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727772/quickly-reading-very-large-tables-as-dataframes-in-r

Comment: +1 for `data.table::fread` from the page Ricardo Saporta links to

Comment: @Ben Any reason you prefer `fread` to the highest-voted solution at that linked page (the one using SQL as an intermediary) ?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft yes, with respect to speed, in my particular use-case  `fread` is about 30x faster than SQL. It's also the fastest in @mnel's speed tests in his/her answer to that Q

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "fastest way" will probably involve using something other than read.csv. However, sticking with read.csv, using pipe may be the way to go:

```
myData <- read.csv(pipe(procName))
```

It avoids reading the full text output into an intermediate buffer (at least before read.csv gets ahold of it).

Some timing comparisons:

```
> write.csv(data.frame(x=rnorm(1e5)), row.names=FALSE, file="norm.csv")
> system.time(d <- read.csv("norm.csv"))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.398   0.004   0.402 
> system.time(d <- read.csv(textConnection(system("cat norm.csv", intern=TRUE))))
   user  system elapsed 
 56.159   0.106  56.095 
> system.time(d <- read.csv(pipe("cat norm.csv")))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.475   0.012   0.531
```

Comment: Just tried this and it seems to be precisely what I was looking for (shaved off some seconds). I had no idea about `pipe`. Thank you!